# Query to total monthly hours for events spanning month borders

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a series of events that are unique and may continue for an arbitrary time.  I need to calculate how may hours the events contribute to a monthly totals, given that the event may commence before a specific month (in which case it will contribute to the previous month as well as the current month) and finish after a specific month.

The data looks something like:

```
Event | StartDate | EndDate   |
-------------------------------
| 1   | 10/01/2015| 11/01/2015|
| 2   | 20/12/2014| 9/01/2015 |
| 3   | 25/01/2015| 14/02/2015|
```

Ultimately, I am try to generate a list grouped by month and year that totals the "Event Hours" for each month (not each event - events within the month are summed).

To be honest, I am not even sure where to start with this.

Comment: Your date fields are `date` or `datetime` ?? because if you want calculate hours right now all are 24h

Comment: Here end date doesn't make sense. Is it dummy value?. End date should be greater than start date
 Event       startdate     enddate
 | 2         | 20/12/2015|  9/01/2015 |

Comment: My error - I will correct it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way is using a months table because you can have empty months.

```
create table months (
   month_id integer,
   date_ini datetime,
   date_end datetime
)
```

Then you do a join with your table.

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d120d/1)

```
WITH ranges as (
    SELECT *
    FROM 
        months m 
        LEFT JOIN events e 
            on   e.StartDate <= m.d_end
            and  e.EndDate >= m.d_begin
 ) 
SELECT r.*, 
       DATEDIFF(hour, 
                CASE 
                    WHEN StartDate > d_begin THEN StartDate
                    WHEN StartDate IS NULL THEN NULL
                    ELSE d_begin
                END, 
                CASE 
                    WHEN EndDate < d_end THEN EndDate
                    WHEN EndDate IS NULL THEN NULL
                    ELSE DATEADD(day,1,d_end)
                END) as Hours
FROM ranges r
```

You have 4 cases

- a event where begin and end are inside the month
- a event where end is beyond the month end
- a event start before and end after a month
- a month with no events.

Comment: Not sure I understand - do you mean join the events table with a table of months in such a way that the union is a list of events (possibly duplicated for events that cross borders) and the time they consume within each month?

Comment: I have just been working through it...in the second row event 2 would commence on the 20th and finish on the 31 (first record) and then commence on the 1st and finish on the 9th of the following month

Comment: I think it might need a CASE switch to set the month breaks or IF Then?

Comment: Done, now only need the `SUM(hours)` by `month_id` ... see how `2015-01-20` to `2015-02-09` give 264 hours (11 days) until 31-january

Comment: This is really helpful - I will do some testing and update you.

Comment: Your calculations are off by 24 hours for each month. It is easy to see if you make an event that starts in January and ends in March. Such event runs for all 28 days of February and should have `28*24=672` hours, but your calculations return `648`. [See event 3](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4b970/1/0) for month 2. But, overall, a nice approach.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov Yesterday I wrote my cases, I saw I miss that case when both date where outside mohth, but was too late and went to bed. That happen when you took the easy route. Will check now. Thanks for pointing my oversight

Comment: @VladimirBaranov Fixed. I just add one day on those cases. I still think this should be a `datetime` field instead just `date` because right now `28/02/2015` can be `28/02/2015 00:00:00` and `1/03/2015 00:00:00` for last day midnight so is ambiguous.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, In these cases I prefer to have `datetime` and start `datetime` inclusive with end `datetime` exclusive. It usually makes logic easier.

Answer (score 0):

Try. This will work.

```
WITH EventInfo AS 
(
   SELECT EVENT, DATEDIFF(HOUR, StartDate,EndDate) AS hours,
        DATEPART(MONTH, EndDate)  AS Month,
        DATEPART(Year, EndDate)  AS Year
    FROM events
)  
SELECT Month, Year, SUM(hours) AS Total_hours
FROM EventInfo
Group By Month, Year
```

Here is the [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ef369/2).

Comment: Thank - will try this as well

Comment: I don't think this takes into account that you may only be counting part of an event in a month?